# Can present simple mean present passive?

Tags: adjectives, verb-forms, deverbal

> Are you married?
>  (Essential Grammar in Use)

They may say the tense of the example is present simple. But it is semantically ‘present passive.’ Is this a usage of present simple in English? If yes, would you let me have some more examples?

Comment: *You are married* cannot parsed as "present perfect continuous": perfect constructions require a form of *HAVE* and continuous constructions require a present participle (*-ing* form). I have edited to change this to "present passive", which is what I think you mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It often happens that participles become so widely used as adjectives that they lose their verbal sense in contexts which do not require a verbal reading.

***Past***, for instance,was originally the past participle of *pass*, but it was 'deverbalized' so long ago that it has had a distinct spelling for three hundred years. **Interesting, interested, boring, bored** are all pretty much independent adjectives; note, for instance, that except in very formal registers you rarely read of anyone *interested **by*** something or *interest**ing** himself in* something.

*Married* is just such a deverbalized adjective: when you ask someone *Are you married?* you are inquiring about their current state, not the ceremony which established it. If you wanted to ask about that you would have to use a specifically verbal construction, something like *Have you gotten married*?

Answer (score 1):

Simple Present and Present Perfect Continuous are used for different purposes.

The Simple Present is used to describe the actual state of something/somebody.

> Are you happy?

> Today, you are sad.

The Present Perfect Continuous is used for something started in the past and continued up until the present.

> Mary has been feeling a little depressed.

> Recently, I have been feeling really tired.

"You are sad." or "You are married." doesn't say anything about the past; they express the current state, which could be the state of the past, or not.

Notice that with some verbs you cannot use the continuous tenses.

> *✲* Sam has been having his car for two years.

> *✲* He has been needing help for a week.

> *✲* She has been wanting a drink for hours.